# Getting concrete type in extension function

Tags: dart

I'd like to get the concrete type in an extension function:

```
extension ObjectExt on Object {
  T applyTo<T>(T Function(typeof this o) op) => op(this);
}
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extension ObjectExt<T> on T {
  R applyTo<R>(R Function(T) op) => op(this as T);
}
```

This will allow to write `x.applyTo(f)` instead of `f(x)`.